# Automatic heroku daily postgres database duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku, database-backups

I have 2 heroku apps. `myapp` and `myapp-sandbox` both are branches of the same repository and have pretty much identical code-bases. I currently have the addon `pgbackups` doing a daily backup of `myapp` which is the live production site. After this backup is made I'd like to automatically reset the database on `myapp-sandbox` and restore the backup of `myapp` instead. As you've probably guessed, `myapp-sandbox` just provides a development sandbox for `myapp` and its api.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine ssh, pg_dump and pg_restore to a pipe that does this in one go. Run something similar to this on the box where myapp-sandbox is on (may require some more tweaking, e.g. rename the database at the end to myapp-sandbox as it will recreate it with the original name):

```
ssh myapp.exmaple.com pg_dump -c -C dbname | pg_restore
```

Comment: I took another look at the docs and found this:

`heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE \`heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp\` --app myapp-sandbox`

Obviously using the heroku gem, but works fine from my mac, any ideas whether this will run on a heroku instance? And whether it will work as a scheduled/cron task?

Comment: Nope sorry never used that, but I don't see an obvious reason why it shouldn't work as you like.